# How do I save uploaded images in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

After uploading and saving the image in a container using ImagePicker, if I switch between pages the image will disappear. How do I get it to 'stick'?

This is the code:

```
class Gallery extends StatefulWidget {
  const Gallery({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Gallery> createState() => _GalleryState();
}

class _GalleryState extends State<Gallery> {
  File? image;

  void getImage({required ImageSource source}) async {
    final file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);

    if (file?.path != null) {
      setState(() {
        image = File(file!.path);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text(
          'Lookbook',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          if (image != null)
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(image: FileImage(image!))),
            )
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'switch between pages'? Its not clear from above snippet how are you using the `Gallery` and at what point you want the image to Stick? Further, can't see a call to `getImage` anywhere

Comment: just past the path on the query parameter of the next route

Comment: Like @faruk said or you can save the path in shared preferences or secure storage and read in on the next page.